# How to set the height of a node to a fixed value java fx scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

My root UI object is a VBox and the first child is a menu bar. The menu bar is added in scene builder. After the scene is set and the stage is shown I call this function.

```
menuBar.setPrefHeight(40.0);
```

I run my program, the height is 40. Then I add an AnchorPane to my root VBox and it's still 40. If I resize the window or if I delete the old AnchorPane and add a new one the height becomes 32. How can I stop this from happening?

Here is my code which constructs an object that builds the AnchorPane

```
private void render(){

    barHeight = menuBar.getHeight();

    boxWidth = vBox.getWidth();
    boxHeight = vBox.getHeight(); 

    barHeight = menuBar.getHeight();
    board = new Board(rc,rc,boxWidth,boxHeight-barHeight);
    //dimensions of AnchorPane based on values passes to contructor above
    board.build(); 

    addPane();
```

Here is my code for adding the AnchorPane to the VBox

```
private void addPane(){
    anchorPane = board.getBoard();

    if(vBox.getChildren().size() == 2){
        vBox.getChildren().remove(1);
    }
    vBox.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
```

I'm also using the ChangeListener Interface which re-renders the AnchorPane whenever the stage's width or height property changes. I don't believe this is causing any problems though.

Comment: javafx can be a bit of a mongrel at times, setting the PrefHeight but getting the height are not the same thing, you need to `menuBar.getPrefHeight` for it to return the same value.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the bar from changing height. The first time I add my AnchorPane there is white space at the bottom. When the AnchorPane is re-rendered the bar's height shrinks and therefore the whitespace is gone

Comment: have you tried setting a minimum height? for the menuBar?

Comment: Set the min and max height to 40 as well. (You can do this in scene builder, instead of in Java, if you prefer.) It looks like you are trying to lay something out (`Board`, whatever that is) by hand, in some sense. It will probably be better to use an appropriate layout pane that does the layout for you, instead of using `AnchorPane`s that don't do much layout computation. Having to observe the stage's dimensions and recalculate things is usually a code smell in JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks. I set the min and max height to 40 and it's working fine now

Comment: @James_D you should post this as an answer